# Hot Reload in Flutter doesn't delete my old changes (VSCode)

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get Flutter up and running so I can begin learning from my new tutorial. However, when I update my code and try to use Flutter's hot reload or hot restart functions, Flutter draws the visual changes on top of what was previously there. In order to get the desired changes I have to fully close and restart the entire app.

https://gyazo.com/21d1a7f0b076f3cbf0cdf9c31bef80d5
https://gyazo.com/dc7b10dd3d5ff17ee9cad8082455aaab

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_flutter_application/screens/authenticate.dart';
import 'home.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return home or authenticate widget
    return Authenticate();
  }
}


class Authenticate extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthenticateState createState() => _AuthenticateState();
}

class _AuthenticateState extends State<Authenticate> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text("Authenticate"),
    );
  }
}




void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Wrapper(),
    );
  }
}
```

^ These two screenshots show you what happens before I make a change and after. After I make the change for the text to draw "Authenticate" instead of "Home", flutter simply draw "Authenticate" over "Home".  The only way to fix this is to restart the app.

If anyone has any insight I would greatly appreciate it, because this has been a very frustrating experience. Thank you!

Comment: Post your code, not screenshots of your code.

Comment: @william3031 The code isn't relevant. I could've put anything in there and Flutter still isn't gonna refresh it, but I'll put it in anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using Scaffold in your app. Try using scaffold as home in your MaterialApp or CupertinoApp. We'll need more of your code in main.dart to help you.

Comment: That's literally all the code. I just started a tutorial and I've followed it 100% the way through

Comment: Hey @JordanHanley , there must be a main.dart file. Main function is entry point for any dart program. In there, you must be using this wrapper widget. It'd be best if you can push the code on github and share the link. I'm sure you must be missing something which instructor skipped thinking of it as trivial.